# How to preserve topology for penetration correction?

Tags: collision-detection, collision-resolution, topography

I have a sorted list of blocks - some may overlap some may not.
Each block has an ideal starting position and may be constrained to one axis.
There are no velocity or acceleration or other forces involved - just the position.
Some blocks are totally fixed and can never be moved (boundary blocks).

How do I solve the penetrations in a way that the blocks don't overlap anymore, but stay in the initial order?

I can easily solve the penetrations with normal position correction methods, like Baumgarte's stabilization in combination with separation axis theorem. The problem though, a separation normal might be found which pushes the block in a way that the order is changed, which is not what I want, because the application I am writing is a numerical simulation with some visualizations.

I created a simple javascript sample to show what I mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/358hra2j/1/

Answer (score 1):

I updated the JSFiddle sample with the solution: [Here's the updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/358hra2j/2/).

It was just two lines of code:

```
var sign = shapeA.id - shapeB.id > 0 ? 1 : -1;
n.multScalar(sign);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, using the sign from the shapes order as a multiplication factor for the normal solved the problem.

Just two lines of code:

```
    // Fix direction based on order of creation
    var sign = shapeA.id - shapeB.id > 0 ? 1 : -1;
    n.multScalar(sign);
```

Comment: It would be nice if you provide a better explanation for future visitors.